# Drupal 7 - Profiles 2 Module - Share profile data or migration

Tags: users

I'm making a platform for 2 types of users:free and paid.

The issue I encounter is the data of the users when updating from one profile to another.

If the user has "free" profile he gets some fields, but when updating the "paid" profile has the same fields+extra.

I first thought of showing the "paid" fields as an extra to the "free" (so the users with "paid" profile have both "free" and "paid" profiles assigned to them), but the issue appears when the user wants to create the profile directly paid as he has no option completing the "free" ones only after he has registered.

Is there any way to make the fields autopopulate (when completing the "field_1" in "free" the data to apear in "field_1" in paid)?
Or to make the data viewable cross multiple profile types?

Conclusion:I need a way for the data to ve visible cross profiles

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a `hook_form_alter()` to add visibility conditions on your `user_profile_form` elements :

Add these kind of attributes on field you want to hide for free users :

```
'#states' => array(
   'visible' => array(
      ':input[name="field_1"]' => array(
         array('value' => 'paid'),
     ),
   ),
),
```